# How can I check method exist in class on TypeScript

Tags: typescript

How check or mark method in parent class that can exist in inherited classes. 
As example I have class B that extends of class A.

```
class A {    
  onSomethingHappend() {
    // how I can check that method exist?  
    this.dependedAction();
  }
}

class B extends A { 
  dependedAction() {
    console.log('dependedAction');
  }
}

const b = new B();

b.onSomethingHappend();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it abstract:

```
abstract class A {    
    onSomethingHappend() {
        this.dependedAction();
    }

    abstract dependedAction(): void;
}
```

Then if class `B` doesn't implement it the compiler will complain.

Another option is:

```
class A {    
    onSomethingHappend() {
        if (typeof (this as any).dependedAction === "function") {
            (this as any).dependedAction();
        }
    }
}
```